# How to refresh, or Loop back to current loaded page in a Windows 10 Universal app?

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app

I have a single paged application for Windows 10 Universal and I would like on a button press for the page (or app) to reset and start again. How is this achieved?

Im thinking it might have something relational to looping too and from a dummy page whilst clearing the Navigation Cache inbetween?

For example:

```
'Main Page (Button Clicked)
    Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(DummyPage))
'Dummy Page (onNavigatedTo)
    Me.NavigationCacheMode = 0
    Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(DummyPage))
```

This just seems a very clunky way of acheiving something quite simple. Is there not a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the NavigationCacheMode to disable, and navigate to the same page

```
Me.Frame.Navigate(GetType(MainPage))
```

Comment: This kept crashing the application with an unhanded exception. It could be the fact that on start of the page it loads some camera settings. As these are already initialised,could this be why its crashing?

Comment: yeah, you need to release camera first before init it again

Comment: Brilliant, so release all my objects, then Navigate back to the same page should fix the issue, thanks for your help